# How to upgrade gitlab 6 to 7 along with old data?

Tags: gitlab

I am using gitlab 6.0.2. Now I want to upgrade to lastest gitlab version. I don't know how to keep old data. I cannot backup because gitlab version mismatch error. The lastest gitlab version is impossible to restore from other version backup. How can I do to keep old data and upgrade to the lastest version of gitlab ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the [From 6.0 to 7.2](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/update/6.x-or-7.x-to-7.14.md) procedure.
It starts by making a backup of the database:

```
cd /home/git/gitlab
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:backup:create RAILS_ENV=production
```

That would allow you to keep the old data.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it. I hope there is no gitlab version mismatch error when I restore the backup on upgraded gitlab.

Comment: @LukeNguyen the idea is *not* to restore the backup, but to use directly the current database for the GitLab 7.x. The backup is only for restoring the database if you have to rollback and re-install GitLab 6.

Comment: Ok, I see. The upgrade process will keep my data and it's available to use on the lastest gitlab version. Backup is only for safe.

Comment: @LukeNguyen yes, that is the idea.

Comment: Thank you VonC. I upgraded from 6.0.2 to 7.3.0 successfully. All data is kept.

Comment: Upgrade fom 6.x to 7.7 https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/update/6.x-or-7.x-to-7.7.md

Comment: the link seems to be gone :/

Comment: @Aiyion.Prime Thank you.  I have restored the link.